# mount works on some directory but not on other

Tags: mount

I have a Beagle Bone Black with an ArmV7 processor running Ubuntu 18.04. I have a 64G microSD card that is partitioned as follows:

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 58 GiB, 62209916928 bytes, 121503744 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xdbf8b7d8

Device         Boot   Start       End   Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1         2048   4098047   4096000   2G 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p2      4098048 121503743 117405696  56G  b W95 FAT32
```

I would like to mount partition 2 on /media/sd:

```
> root@bbbtest:~# mount -v /dev/mmcblk0p2 /media/sd
mount: /dev/mmcblk0p2 mounted on /media/sd.
```

Note that I am logged in as root. Looks good but:

```
> root@bbbtest:~# lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0      179:0    0   58G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1  179:1    0    2G  0 part /usr
└─mmcblk0p2  179:2    0   56G  0 part
mmcblk1      179:8    0  1.8G  0 disk
└─mmcblk1p1  179:9    0  1.8G  0 part /
mmcblk1boot0 179:16   0    1M  1 disk
mmcblk1boot1 179:24   0    1M  1 disk
mmcblk1rpmb  179:32   0  128K  0 disk
```

Device is not mounted but if I mount it on /root/xxx

```
> root@bbbtest:~# mount -v /dev/mmcblk0p2 /root/xxx
mount: /dev/mmcblk0p2 mounted on /root/xxx.
root@bbbtest:~# lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0      179:0    0   58G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1  179:1    0    2G  0 part /usr
└─mmcblk0p2  179:2    0   56G  0 part /root/xxx
mmcblk1      179:8    0  1.8G  0 disk
└─mmcblk1p1  179:9    0  1.8G  0 part /
mmcblk1boot0 179:16   0    1M  1 disk
mmcblk1boot1 179:24   0    1M  1 disk
mmcblk1rpmb  179:32   0  128K  0 disk
```

It mounts just fine. I noted that the date of directory xxx is Dec 31  1969 and I can't change the mode bits. As requested, I did df -hTa /media/sd

```
root@bbbtest:/media# df -hTa /media/sd
Filesystem     Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk1p1 ext4  1.8G  730M  931M  44% /
```

and df -hTa /media which gave the same result.
However I also created directory /mnt/sd and had no difficulty mounting the partition there which solved my problem practically. I am still curious as to why /media/sd did not work

```
root@bbbtest:/media# mount -L BKUPFS
root@bbbtest:/media# lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0      179:0    0   58G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1  179:1    0    2G  0 part /usr
└─mmcblk0p2  179:2    0   56G  0 part /mnt/sd
mmcblk1      179:8    0  1.8G  0 disk
└─mmcblk1p1  179:9    0  1.8G  0 part /
mmcblk1boot0 179:16   0    1M  1 disk
mmcblk1boot1 179:24   0    1M  1 disk
mmcblk1rpmb  179:32   0  128K  0 disk
```

As requested, I did

```
root@bbbprod:~# dmesg -C
root@bbbprod:~# mount -vvv /dev/mmcblk0p2 /media/sd
mount: /dev/mmcblk0p2 mounted on /media/sd.
```

Then checked with mount which showed that it was not really mounted and did dmesg.

```
root@bbbprod:~# dmesg
root@bbbprod:~#
```

Comment: Is it actually not mounted or does `lsblk` just do not show the mount? Use the command ``mount` or `df -hTa /media/sd` to verify if it is mounted. Please also add the output of `df -hTa /media` to your question by editing the question.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  I did as you asked.  The partition was not mounted. It mounted fine on /root/xxx and /mnt/sd. I am really curious as to what was special about /media/sd.

Comment: Hm, strange. Is there anything in the kernel log? Do `dmesg -C`, then `mount -vvv /dev/mmcblk0p2 /media/sd`and then `dmesg`. This should give you an output and add that to your question. A complete output of `mount` would also be helpful.

Comment: Still not mounting.  Strange that it mounted fine on /root/xxx and /mnt/sd.  I opted to mount it on /mnt/sd and solved the problem but it is really strange.